# justify the line in latex beamer

Tags: beamer, themes

How to justify the line in latex beamer presentation. Using below code I am using to make a slide presentation which I attached below, but the text is not appearing good decorate. I tried to used \Justifying command but it's not working.

The second paragraph of the slide does not look well decorate the text.

```
\documentclass[handout,t]{beamer}
\begin{document}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
% -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
\begin{frame}{District wise Cumulative Rainfall as on 23rd June, 2017}
\begin{columns}[onlytextwidth,T]
    \begin{column}{.45\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{MONSOON-CUMULATIVE}
    \end{column}
    \begin{column}{.47\textwidth}
        \begin{itemize}
%%          \JustifyingParfillskip
%           \JustifyingParindent
            \item Central and North part of the regions under deficit category of rainfall (yellow and red zones). 
            \item The excess rainfall received in Bharuch, Narmada and Dahod while others region received normal rainfall (Green and blue zones). 
        \end{itemize}
    \end{column}
\end{columns}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
%------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

[image]

Comment: You cannot use a package after `\begin{document}`.

Comment: Ok. What's the another way to do it

Comment: Use it before `\begin{document}` (even TeX gives you this tip in the error message).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code has two primary issues:

- You have a `\usepackage` outside of the preamble and
- you use an inexistent macro `\Justifying` (`ragged2e` defines `\justifying`)

[image: justified]

```
\documentclass[handout,demo,t]{beamer}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\begin{document}
% -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
\begin{frame}{District wise Cumulative Rainfall as on 23rd June, 2017}
\begin{columns}[onlytextwidth,T]
    \begin{column}{.45\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{MONSOON-CUMULATIVE}
    \end{column}
    \begin{column}{.47\textwidth}
        \begin{itemize}
            \item\justifying Central and North part of the regions under deficit category of rainfall (yellow and red zones). 
            \item The excess rainfall received in Bharuch, Narmada and Dahod while others region received normal rainfall (Green and blue zones). 
        \end{itemize}
    \end{column}
\end{columns}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you. but problem is `\justifying` command is not appearing in my beamer presentation. When i type J its showing one two option  `\JustifyingParfillskip`      `\JustifyingParindent`.

Comment: @SWAT What do you mean with not appearing? Syntax auto completion? That's no indicator for commands! Just try to compile my file and it works.

Comment: @SWAT If you don't believe me, just check out the [`ragged2e` manual](https://ctan.org/pkg/ragged2e).

Comment: Thank you very much. It was a just space issue. Now it's working perfectly.